# Teamviewer logs me out when I start Chrome browser on ubuntu

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, logout, teamviewer

I noticed a strange behavior on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 and latest Teamviewer version. When I connect remotely to this Ubuntu machine, everything works just find, but as soon as I start Chrome, Ubuntu logs me out, and I cannot connect to it anymore, even using "Remote Control using password" option, or any other.

Does anyone know what is it related to? Maybe Keychain, or anything else?

Thank you.